# OpenGL - render timing jitter makes animation jerky

Tags: linux, opengl, timing

A small testprogram (see below) shows jerky output, which, I assume, is caused by a strange timing jitter during OpenGL glutSwapBuffer(). The testprogram quite often shows a very long rendering time for a single frame compared to the average (~330 micro seconds vs. ~5.8 milli seconds on my machine)
The output of the program shows:

```
[...]
render time:   330us
render time:   372us
render time:   330us
render time:   331us
render time:  5820us
render time:   335us
render time:   332us
render time:   324us
render time:   346us
[...]
```

Setup:
Fast PC (Intel i7 CPU @3.2GHz), Ubuntu 12.04, NVIDIA GTS450 board, recent GL driver:
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTS 450/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 4.3.0 NVIDIA 310.19
Samsung Display (23" @60Hz I assume, as all those have 60Hz)

In the testcase above I've explicitly overruled vblank sync by: 
  __GL_SYNC_TO_VBLANK=0

Having vblank enabled I get quite instable timings as well:

__GL_SYNC_TO_VBLANK=1

```
[...]
render time:  9169us
render time: 14548us
render time: 14613us
render time: 16057us
render time: 18075us
[...]
```

I also played with other parameters, such as putting the X server at high priority
(sudo schedtool -p 0 -n -20 -N `pgrep X`) or putting the program itself at high priority (chrt -p -a --fifo 99 ...)

Still the jerky animation remains - which (this is my assumption) is caused by the strange timing.

Timing without `glutSwapBuffers();' in the code shows very stable output:

```
[...]
render time:     2us
render time:     2us
render time:     2us
render time:     1us
render time:     2us
[...]
```

So an external (other process) influence can be ruled out.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Any idea how to improve?

### The program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <time.h>

GLfloat gfPosX = 0.0;
GLfloat gfDeltaX = .01;

#define TS_TOUSEC(x) (x.tv_sec * 1000000L + (x.tv_nsec / 1000))
struct timespec t1, t2;

void Draw() {
    int x = 0;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t1);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(gfPosX, 0.25, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(gfPosX, 0.75,0.0);
    glEnd();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t2);
    glutSwapBuffers();
    printf("render time: %5uus\n", TS_TOUSEC(t2) - TS_TOUSEC(t1));

    gfPosX += gfDeltaX;
    if (gfPosX >= 1.0 || gfPosX <= 0.0) {
        gfDeltaX = -gfDeltaX;
    }
}

void Timer(int iUnused)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(5, Timer, 0);
}

void Initialize() {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}

int main(int iArgc, char** cppArgv) {
    glutInit(&iArgc, cppArgv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(250, 250);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
    glutCreateWindow("XoaX.net");
    Initialize();
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    Timer(0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using your time in any way other than just measuring it? Because even with vertical sync, it might be wise to either use fixed update frame, or change the DeltaX basing on the elapsed time. That way you'll compensate for longer frames.

Comment: So far the time is just for measuring - this is already a downstripped program - the real application is far more complex; I tracked down the jerky output to this now - well at least I think, this jitter is the problem.

Comment: 5ms would correspond pretty closely to a context switch.

Answer (score 0):

I'd not use this one:

> ```
> clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t1);
> ```

CLOCK_REALTIME shows wall time (i.e. time as shown by a clock hanging on a wall), i.e. its not guaranteed to be monotonic. It may a little forward or backward, as time deamons make adjustments to it.

For measuring frame rendering time you want CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW.

In your timing without SwapBuffers you're only measuring the time it takes to issue the rendering calls. Not the rendering time itself. You must add a glFinish to get that, so that the command queue is actually executed.

For all pactical purposes you should not time it takes to render a frame, but the time between individual frames, i.e. the intervall between calls to the display function. This gives much more accurate animation.

To account for input lag, I'd use a Kalman filter to predict input state when rendering finishes (for that you need the frame rendering time, just collect statistics) and use the predicted input state for frame advancement.

Comment: Thanx for the feedback - Changing to CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW didn't change the behavior - which is quite obvious, as typically the timeupdates through e.g. NTP and others don't happen that often.

In the meantime I found [link]http://paradoxuncreated.com/Blog/wordpress/?p=2268

Using the tips which I found there the situation improves:
- changing the desktop to lubuntu (instead of ubuntu/gnome-shell)
- using the low-jitter kernel (found on that website)
- finally using the kernel commandline option: idle=poll
the last one really brought down the jitter